# Django наследование и отображение

Tags: python, django, form

Есть модель models.py:

```
    class DeviceList(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='deviceList')
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    device = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Вот такая форма forms.py:

class AddDevice(forms.ModelForm):

```
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceList
        widgets = {
            'imei': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'device': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
        fields = ("username","imei","address", "device")
```

B вот такая 'views.py:'

```
def addDevice(request):
    userId = request.user.pk
    #form = forms.AddDevice
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AddDevice(request.POST)
        print()
        if form.is_valid():
            #print(form)
            form.save()
            print("save")
    else:
        form = forms.AddDevice()



    return render(request,'mainsite/add_device.html', {'form': form})
```

Поля которые заполняются с html файла это 'imei', 'address', 'device', но при этом username должен заполняться относительно авторезированного пользователя автоматически.
После чего данные должны отправляться на сервер.

Все поля заполняются корректно, а вот не могу победить автоматическое заполнение usernam в форму.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать `initial`

```
def addDevice(request):
    userId = request.user.pk
    #form = forms.AddDevice
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AddDevice(request.POST)
        print()
        if form.is_valid():
            #print(form)
            form.save()
            print("save")
    else:
        form = forms.AddDevice(initial={"username": request.user.username})

    return render(request,'mainsite/add_device.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Нк рабоатет. Пробовал.